# Conditionally extracting consecutive decreasing numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with consecutive decreases of numbers and some with decrease and increase then decrease again (in groups).

I need to extract this consecutive decrease part and remove the unsystematic increase and decrease part!

here is the test data of what I mean

```
test=data.frame(set=gl(3,9),vals=c(c(10,10,10, 9.9, 8.1, 1, 1,1,1),c(10,10,10, 9.9,6.1,1, 2,1,1),c(10,10,10, 7,6,1,2,0,1)))

> test
   set vals
1    1 10.0
2    1 10.0
3    1 10.0
4    1  9.9
5    1  8.1
6    1  1.0
7    1  1.0
8    1  1.0
9    1  1.0
10   2 10.0
11   2 10.0
12   2 10.0
13   2  9.9
14   2  6.1
15   2  1.0
16   2  2.0
17   2  1.0
18   2  1.0
19   3 10.0
20   3 10.0
21   3 10.0
22   3  7.0
23   3  6.0
24   3  1.0
25   3  2.0
26   3  0.0
27   3  1.0
```

I write the simple function called `slice_it` to find the consecutive decrease s in the data

```
slice_it <-  function(x){

  temp <- c(0,diff(x))

  }

library(dplyr)
test%>%
  group_by(set)%>%
  mutate(diff_x=slice_it(vals))
```

which gives

```
  set vals diff_x
1    1 10.0    0.0  #remove
2    1 10.0    0.0  #remove
3    1 10.0    0.0  #remove
4    1  9.9   -0.1  #keep 
5    1  8.1   -1.8  #keep 
6    1  1.0   -7.1  #keep
7    1  1.0    0.0  #remove 
8    1  1.0    0.0  #remove
9    1  1.0    0.0  #remove
10   2 10.0    0.0  #remove
11   2 10.0    0.0  #remove
12   2 10.0    0.0  #remove
13   2  9.9   -0.1  #keep
14   2  6.1   -3.8  #keep
15   2  1.0   -5.1  #keep
16   2  2.0    1.0  #remove
17   2  1.0   -1.0  #remove 
18   2  1.0    0.0  #remove
19   3 10.0    0.0  #remove
20   3 10.0    0.0  #remove
21   3 10.0    0.0  #remove
22   3  7.0   -3.0  #keep
23   3  6.0   -1.0  #keep
24   3  1.0   -5.0  #keep
25   3  2.0    1.0  #remove
26   3  0.0   -2.0  #remove
27   3  1.0    1.0  #remove
```

if I add filter to the `dplyr` chain
which gives

```
filter(diff_x<0)

# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   set [3]
  set    vals  diff_x
 1 1       9.9 -0.1000 #keep
 2 1       8.1 -1.8    #keep
 3 1       1   -7.1    #keep 
 4 2       9.9 -0.1000 #keep 
 5 2       6.1 -3.8    #keep
 6 2       1   -5.1    #keep 
 7 2       1   -1      #remove
 8 3       7   -3      #keep
 9 3       6   -1      #keep
10 3       1   -5      #keep
11 3       0   -2      #remove
```

the rows that I indicated with `#remove` still remains as their `diff`<0. But this happening after an increase of the previous number so it should be removed!

the expected should be look like

```
  set vals diff_x

4    1  9.9   -0.1  #keep 
5    1  8.1   -1.8  #keep 
6    1  1.0   -7.1  #keep
13   2  9.9   -0.1  #keep
14   2  6.1   -3.8  #keep
15   2  1.0   -5.1  #keep
22   3  7.0   -3.0  #keep
23   3  6.0   -1.0  #keep
24   3  1.0   -5.0  #keep
```

How can I achieve this.
Thanks!

ps. Slice from the last part would not help because how many rows from the bottom is uncertain.

Comment: @Hack-R Because its a consecutive decrease after row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I understood you correctly, we could use a second `diff` on the `lag`ged values; this reproduces your expected output

```
test %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    group_by(set) %>%
    mutate(
        diff = c(0, diff(vals)),
        diff2 = c(0, diff(lag(vals)))) %>%
    filter(diff < 0 & diff2 <= 0) %>%
    select(-diff2)
## A tibble: 9 x 4
## Groups:   set [3]
#    row set    vals    diff
#  <int> <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4 1      9.90 -0.1000
#2     5 1      8.10 -1.80
#3     6 1      1.00 -7.10
#4    13 2      9.90 -0.1000
#5    14 2      6.10 -3.80
#6    15 2      1.00 -5.10
#7    22 3      7.00 -3.00
#8    23 3      6.00 -1.00
#9    24 3      1.00 -5.00
```

---

### Update

To re-use your `slice_it` function

```
slice_it <-  function(x) c(0, diff(x))
test %>%
    group_by(set) %>%
    mutate(diff_x = slice_it(vals)) %>%
    filter(diff_x < 0 & slice_it(lag(vals)) <= 0)
```

Comment: Perfect! Could you add this diff functions and filter into `slice_it` function ? I tried to add the first filter int the OP but it raised an error!

Comment: what is the `rowid_to_column` ? could not find function "rowid_to_column"

Comment: @Alexander `tibble::rowid_to_column` stores row numbers in a separate column; I only included it here to make it easier to compare with your expected output (which also includes row numbers); you can safely remove that line if necessary. I don't understand what you want to add to `slice_it`; `slice_it` is quite unnecessary as it only creates a new column which you can do directly through `mutate`. You *could* define a function `my_filter` that hides the double `mutate` calls plus `filter` in a separate function. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks. Ok I understand the `tibble::rowid_to_column` part. I always want to have less line of code in the `dplyr` chain that is way I asked to put everything into `slice_it`. Could you add your `my_filter` function at least? So I can know how to built one:)

Comment: I've added an update where I re-use your `slice_it` function; personally, I prefer the explicit `tidyverse` chain, it helps with readability IMO; especially with complex manipulations, external function calls often make it more obscure.